# ¿Cómo cambiar el type de un input de hidden a text mediante el dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

El caso es el siguiente tengo un `<input type="hidden">` el cual, cuando le doy a un botón quiero cambiarle el `type="hidden"` a `text`

```js
let descrip = document.getElementById('descripcion6').setAttribute('type', 'text');
```

```html
    <input type="hidden" name="descripcion6">
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posible solución con `jQuery`.

Tendrías que agregar el ID a tu `input` **descripcion6**

```js
$("#descripcion6").prop("type", "text");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="descripcion6">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo logré solucionar con un método de `jQuery`

```js
$('#descripcion6').prop('type', 'text')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="descripcion6" id="descripcion6">
```

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptada tu solución y con eso los demás sabremos que está fue la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Hola a tu **input** ponle un id, para seleccionar un solo elemento desde la funcion. Al final lo que pides es asi según entiendo.

```js
function cambiarTipo(){
  document.getElementById('descripcion6').setAttribute('type', 'text');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" name="descripcion6" id="descripcion6">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="cambiarTipo();">Cambiar a text</button>
    </body>
</html>
```